# Camera sometimes flipping upside down when the mouse is moved quickly

Tags: java, 3d, camera, libgdx

I'm trying to use 3D in LibGDX however the camera flips upside down and nothing I do seems to prevent it with no known cause as to why it happens.

I've tested each axis of rotation individually and it works perfectly however when they both are used together it sometimes flips upside down.

```
public void create () {
    environment = new Environment();
    environment.set(new ColorAttribute(ColorAttribute.AmbientLight, 0.4f, 0.4f, 0.4f, 1f));
    environment.add(new DirectionalLight().set(0.8f, 0.8f, 0.8f, -2.5f, -5, -10));

    modelBatch = new ModelBatch();

    cam = new PerspectiveCamera(67, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
    cam.position.set(0, 0, 0);
    cam.lookAt(-10,-10,-10);
    cam.near = 1f;
    cam.far = 300f;
    cam.update();

    ModelBuilder modelBuilder = new ModelBuilder();
    model = modelBuilder.createBox(5, 5, 5, 
        new Material(ColorAttribute.createDiffuse(Color.GREEN)),
        Usage.Position | Usage.Normal);

    instance = new ModelInstance(model);

    instance.transform.translate(-10, -10, -10);

    Gdx.input.setCursorCatched(true);
    Gdx.input.setCursorPosition(Gdx.graphics.getWidth() / 2, Gdx.graphics.getHeight() / 2);
}

@Override
public void render () {
    Gdx.gl.glViewport(0, 0, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL20.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    isup = false;
    ispressed = false;
    Vector3 direction = cam.direction.cpy();

    Vector3 crossProduct = new Vector3(); //CROSSPRODUCT OF PLAYER DIRECTION AGAINST Y AXIS
    crossProduct.x = -direction.z;
    crossProduct.y = 0;
    crossProduct.z = direction.x;

    differencey = -Gdx.input.getY() + (Gdx.graphics.getHeight() / 2);
    if ((cam.direction.y > -0.8 || differencey > 0) && (cam.direction.y < 0.8 || differencey < 0)) {
        if (differencey > 50) {
            differencey = 50;
        }
        cam.rotate(crossProduct, differencey / 10);

        cam.update();
    }

    differencex = Gdx.input.getX() - (Gdx.graphics.getWidth() / 2);

    cam.rotate(new Vector3(0, -1, 0), differencex / 10);

    cam.update();

    modelBatch.begin(cam);
    modelBatch.render(instance, environment);
    modelBatch.end();

    Gdx.input.setCursorPosition(Gdx.graphics.getWidth() / 2, Gdx.graphics.getHeight() / 2);

    if (Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.ESCAPE)) {
        Gdx.app.exit();
    }
```

The camera movement should be restricted so that the camera cannot be moved upwards or downwards any further if the user is looking almost straight up or straight down respectively however the camera sometimes moves past this restriction anyway.